# Showing JSON object in a table using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to fill an element on a website with data from a JSON object. For formatting, I try to use an HTML table.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
teams = {
    "1": {
        "channels": {
            "1_1": {
                "displayName": "General",
                "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
            },
            "1_2": {
                "description": "Hier staan de tabbladen van het Ticketsysteem",
                "displayName": "TicketSysteem"
            }
        },
        "displayName": "ASC Systeembeheer",
        "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
    },
    "2": {
        "channels": {
            "2_1": {
                "description": "Handleidingen",
                "displayName": "Handleidingen"
            },
            "2_2": {
                "description": null,
                "displayName": "Externe toegang"
            }
        }
    }
}

var list = document.querySelector('#list');
list.innerHTML = '<table>';
for (let id in teams){
  list.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${id}</td></tr>`;
}
list.innerHTML += '</table>'
```

It does place a table open and close tag, but it doesn't have any content.
The content is placed after the table close tag without the [tr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) or [td](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) tags.

I'm kind of flabbergasted about this. I was expecting a table, a simple one, but at least one I could build on.

```js
teams = {
  "1": {
    "channels": {
      "1_1": {
        "displayName": "General",
        "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
      },
      "1_2": {
        "description": "Hier staan de tabbladen van het Ticketsysteem",
        "displayName": "TicketSysteem"
      }
    },
    "displayName": "ASC Systeembeheer",
    "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
  },
  "2": {
    "channels": {
      "2_1": {
        "description": "Handleidingen",
        "displayName": "Handleidingen"
      },
      "2_2": {
        "description": null,
        "displayName": "Externe toegang"
      }
    }
  }
}

var list = document.querySelector('#list');
list.innerHTML = '<table>';
for (let id in teams) {
  list.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${id}</td></tr>`;
}
list.innerHTML += '</table>'
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <p>blaat</p>
</div>
```

What is going on? What don't I get?

I've got a [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen) set up: https://codepen.io/peter-kaagman/pen/ExOmwgW

Comment: Please be aware that `teams` is _not_ JSON. What is sometimes called "a JSON object" is just a JavaScript object.

Comment: What do you expect table like what?

Comment: `list.innerHTML += '</table>'` doesn't look valid and likely doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @evolutionxbox What is sometimes called a "JSON object" is actually a string. After calling `JSON.parse()` on that string, you get a JavaScript object.

Comment: @ScottMarcus sure. In this case Peter used "JSON obect" when they meant a JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every time** you modify `innerHTML` you modify the **DOM** and the browser normalises it. You are not modifying the HTML source code.

---

> ```
> list.innerHTML = '<table>';
> ```

Here you create a table element. The missing `</table>` is added by the browser's error recovery.

---

> ```
> list.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${id}</td></tr>`;
> ```

Not you append a `<tr>` element to the contents of the node.

So the contents you are trying to create are:

```
<table></table>
<tr><td>${id}</td></tr>
```

… which doesn't make sense.

---

If you are going to use `innerHTML` then build a string with the complete value you want to assign, **then** assign it to `innerHTML` **in one go**.

```
let table = '<table>';
for (let id in teams){
  table += `<tr><td>${id}</td></tr>`;
}
table += '</table>';
list.innerHTML = table;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you need to set `innerHTML` to a **complete** valid HTML string. You cannot append part of a HTML element in one operation, then add content in another, then close the tag again.

To fix the problem concatenate the HTML in to a string variable, then set `innerHTML` ***once***, when that HTML is complete:

```js
teams = {
  "1": {
    "channels": {
      "1_1": {
        "displayName": "General",
        "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
      },
      "1_2": {
        "description": "Hier staan de tabbladen van het Ticketsysteem",
        "displayName": "TicketSysteem"
      }
    },
    "displayName": "ASC Systeembeheer",
    "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
  },
  "2": {
    "channels": {
      "2_1": {
        "description": "Handleidingen",
        "displayName": "Handleidingen"
      },
      "2_2": {
        "description": null,
        "displayName": "Externe toegang"
      }
    }
  }
}

var list = document.querySelector('#list');
let html = '<table>';
for (let id in teams) {
  html += `<tr><td>${id}</td></tr>`;
}
html += '</table>';
list.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use [`innerHTML`](https://medium.com/@verity.carlos/why-you-shouldnt-use-innerhtml-and-what-to-use-instead-ed99d064a416). Use the available *[document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)* methods.

Here is an example for your code.

```js
const teamsObj = {
  "1": {
    "channels": {
      "1_1": {
        "displayName": "General",
        "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
      },
      "1_2": {
        "description": "Hier staan de tabbladen van het Ticketsysteem",
        "displayName": "TicketSysteem"
      }
    },
    "displayName": "ASC Systeembeheer",
    "description": "Systeembeheer cq ICT Service groep"
  },
  "2": {
    "channels": {
      "2_1": {
        "description": "Handleidingen",
        "displayName": "Handleidingen"
      },
      "2_2": {
        "description": null,
        "displayName": "Externe toegang"
      }
    }
  }
}

const list = document.querySelector('#list');
const table = document.createElement(`table`);
const aRow = document.createElement(`tr`);
const aCell = document.createElement(`td`);
const rows = Object.entries(teamsObj).forEach( ([id, value]) => {
  // Create a new row by cloning [aRow]
  const row = aRow.cloneNode();
  // Create a new table cell by cloning [aCell]
  const cell = aCell.cloneNode();
  // Fill the cell with the id
  cell.textContent = id;
  // Append the cell to the row
  row.append(cell);
  // create a string representation of the value
  // and add it to a new cell (using a different
  // way to create a cell)
  const valueStr = JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
  row.append( Object.assign( cell.cloneNode(), { innerHTML: valueStr} ) );
  // Append the row to the table
  table.append(row);
});

// empty div#list
list.textContent = ``;

// The table now only exists in memory
// so append it to div#list to add it to
// the document.
list.append(table);
```

```css
td:first-child {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 40px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <p>blaat</p>
</div>
```